# MPI - Error 1722

Tags: cmd, mpi

При запуске программы через консоль командой: mpiexec.exe -n 8 KR.exe, появляется ошибка:

```
[0..7]fatal error
Fatal error in MPI_Init: Other MPI_error,error stack:
MPI_Init(argc_p=0x0069F90C, argv_c=0x0069F910) failed .. (кодировка не даёт понять)(errno 1722)

Aborting: mpi application on namePC is unable to the smpd manager on (null): 7309 error 1722.

job aborted:
[ranks] message

--
Windows 8
Microsoft HPC Pack 2012 SDK

--
```

Пытался удалять MPI и устанавливать только HPC, ошибка повторяется, как я понимаю ошибка в разных версиях smpd и mpiexec.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я сделал следующее:

- 1) обновил с Windows 7(у меня была семёрка) до Windows 10, переустановил MSVisual Studio 2017 (по совету моих знакомых);
- 2)скачал с официального сайта Microsoft и установил в таком
  порядке: а)MSMPI v B9.0.1 b)MSMPI v B8;
- 3) открыл cmd и ввёл команду set MSMPI, она выдала пути установок MPI

В Visual Studio,создав новый проект,открыв его свойства:

- 4)Пункт "Отладкa": раздел "Команда" указал путь к mpiexec.exe (в моём
  случае -D:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\mpiexec.exe) 
  раздел "Аргументы команды" указал кол-во процессов (в моём случае -  -n 4
  "$(TargetPath)")
- 5)Пункт "Каталоги VC++":раздел "Включаемые каталоги" указал путь с
  папкой Include (в моём случае - D:\Program Files %28x86%29\Microsoft
  SDKs\MPI\Include\x64;$(IncludePath) ); раздел "Каталоги библиотек" 
  указал путь с папкой Lib (в моём случае - D:\Program Files
  %28x86%29\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Lib\x64;$(LibraryPath));
- 6)Пункт "С\С++": раздел "Дополнительные каталоги включаемых файлов"
  указал $(MSMPI_INC);$(MSMPI_INC)\x64;
- 7)Пукнт "Компоновщик -> Ввод": раздел "Дополнительные зависимости"
  добавил в конец записи (после odbccp32.lib;) msmpi.lib;(именно с
  точкой запятой)

В случае, если у вас 32 разрядная версия, то вместо х64 указывайте х86.